# What's the difference between int** as a parameter and int** in main function?

Tags: c++, c, pointers

A question in following codes.
The result is :

9232312
2

The type of `y` in `fun` is 'a pointer to a pointer to `int`'.Then `*y` must be a pointer to `int`. So it should printed an address number(like 9232312 etc.), but why is the result 2?

```
void fun(int **y){
    printf("%d\n", *(y+1));
}
int main(){
    int a[2][2] = {1,2,3,4};
    printf("%d\n", *(a+1));
    fun((int **)a);
    return 0;
}
```

It is not the question of pointer or array that I am confused of. I dont understand why the result is different？why the converting from array to pointer occurs error? Apparently your comments and marking my question duplicate are not helping ..

Comment: There is no `y` variable in `main` to print. I don't see how this can compile.

Comment: arrays != pointers!!

Comment: There is no `int**` in your `main`, it is as simple as that.

Comment: The reason why you needed an explicit cast to convert `a` to an `int**` is because `a` is not an `int**`. Compiler warnings exist for a reason.